# Disabling heapster health checks in Kubernetes 1.10

Tags: kubernetes, heapster

While doing `kubectl cluster-info dump` , I see alot of:

```
2018/10/18 14:47:47 Metric client health check failed: the server could not find the requested resource (get services heapster). Retrying in 30 seconds.
2018/10/18 14:48:17 Metric client health check failed: the server could not find the requested resource (get services heapster). Retrying in 30 seconds.
2018/10/18 14:48:47 Metric client health check failed: the server could not find the requested resource (get services heapster). Retrying in 30 seconds.
2018/10/18 14:49:17 Metric client health check failed: the server could not find the requested resource (get services heapster). Retrying in 30 seconds.
2018/10/18 14:49:47 Metric client health check failed: the server could not find the requested resource (get services heapster). Retrying in 30 seconds.
2018/10/18 14:50:17 Metric client health check failed: the server could not find the requested resource (get services heapster). Retrying in 30 seconds.
2018/10/18 14:50:47 Metric client health check failed: the server could not find the requested resource (get services heapster). Retrying in 30 seconds.
```

Maybe this is a bug that will be fixed in new version ( heapster is deprecated anyway in new versions) , but is there anyway to disable these checks to avoid these noisy messges.

Comment: i have another one: `I1022 04:16:08.129640       1 wrap.go:42] GET /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster/proxy/healthz: (20.207558ms) 404`, but there are no any resources somehow related to `heapster`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find Heapster deprecation timeline [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/blob/master/docs/deprecation.md).

I found that in Kubernetes cluster 1.10 version `kubernetes-dashboard` Pod produces such kind of error messages:

`kubectl --namespace=kube-system log <kubernetes-dashboard-Pod>`

> 2018/10/22 13:04:36 Metric client health check failed: the server
>   could not find the requested resource (get services heapster).
>   Retrying in 30 seconds.

It seems that `kubernetes-dashboard` still requires Heapster service for metrics and graph purposes.

Comment: thanks , yeah , I noticed later it is due to dashboard , it should be disbaled in dashboard as well